# How to provide a preference settings for long running jobs in RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am currently facing a issue with a long running job in my rcp application .On starting the job i have a progressbar with 3 buttons and one checkbox .And if user  checked the checkbox and pressed the run in background then my progressbar dialog  is not coming back.
So  I tried to use a preference page where User can check and unchecked this settings .But I learnt that  I have to use some internal things to do that   `WorkbenchPlugin.PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue( IPreferenceConstants.RUN_IN_BACKGROUND, false );`

And according to practice I should not do that .So is there any better way or is there any way to remove run in background checkbox from the progressbar dilaog.

Any help on this will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without using internal classes with:

```
IPersistentPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "org.eclipse.ui.workbench");

store.setValue("RUN_IN_BACKGROUND", false);

store.save();
```

Comment: IPreferenceConstants.RUN_IN_BACKGROUND is also  internal.Anything else is there which is not internal

Comment: Removed `IPreferenceConstants`. Of course if the plugin or preference name ever changes this will start to fail, but this is unlikely for this setting.